# Javascript POST enforcing pre-flight request

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, cors

I'm trying to send data to a server through my frontend. I have the following code,

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST');
xhr.send(data);
```

The `data` is a JSON string which should be sent to the server. However, I get the following response on the server `"[1m[35mOPTIONS /addUser HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -`. It's not clear why the request is being sent as `OPTIONS` when `Content-type` is set as `text/plain` i.e. the request should not be pre-flighted.

How can I send data to the server using CORS?

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` are not request headers, they're *response* headers.  Do not set them in your request.